# Crosstab() function in postgresql causes error. (tablefunc module installed)

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I am using postgresql 9.3.9.

I did `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;`successfully. 
Now, when I try to do a simple crosstab query, e.g:

```
select * from crosstab('select col_1, col_2 from table order by 1,2')
```

I get this error:

```
Error in query: ERROR: function crosstab(unknown) does not exist
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried adding an explicit cast to text, but that did not help.

Comment: What does `select count(*) from information_schema.routines where routine_name like 'crosstab%'` give you? Maybe you forgot to `commit` the `create extension`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that was indeed the problem. I did not realise that CREATE EXTENSION commands needed to be commited - even though I've installed an extension before. Anyway, that worked, thanks. If you add the comment as an answer, I can accept it, so the question can be closed.

Comment: Another common mistake is to `CREATE EXTENSION` in the wrong database btw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if the extension is really installed, do:

```
select count(*) from information_schema.routines where routine_name like 'crosstab%'
```

If it returns 0, you should check if you installed the extension in the right database, and whether you commited the `CREATE EXTENSION` statement.